# lightweight alternative for pandas

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, aws-lambda

I am trying to create an AWS lambda function written in Python.
Lambda function create fails with following error:

> Unzipped file size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes.

Following is my requirements.txt

```
numpy
pandas
pprint
pint
flask
scipy
gunicorn
pydblite
jsonschema
matplotlib
sklearn
```

After removing all `test`, `*.pyc` and `*-info*` files following packages are the top contributors to the volume.

```
scipy  126M
pandas 64M
numpy  64M
matplotlib 29M
```

I have replaced pandas' read_excel with `xlsx`.

If there is any way I can get size reduced version of packages, that would be great.
Otherwise, looking for alternatives of:

- pandas's `DataFrame`

Comment: I guess he meant what kind of functions you need. Cannot you use a numpy array instead of pandas? I have used numpy for a long time before discovering about pandas, but pandas just makes life easier, it's not a must to run an application.

Comment: I'd suggest re posting this question to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Where it will be on topic.

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks, Paul. Posted on Software Recommendations.

Comment: @Wli Trying to re-implement with `numpy` arrays. 
As it's someone else's code, taking a lot of time, I had posted this question.

Comment: I don't see what you could do without rewriting some of the code. It's not as if there's some drop-in replacement for pandas that uses much less disk space.

Comment: Thanks @Kodiologist. I have replaced DataFrame related code with NumPy arrays.

Comment: I have made a simplified kind of pandas, called *tabel*. Its super small and has all the basic DataFrame functionality: https://pypi.org/project/tabel/

Answer (score 4):

As @Kodiologist suggested, had switched to numpy arrays. As I already have numpy as dependency, this turned out to be a better alternative to DataFrame of pandas.

Comment: I'm yet to migrate, but [Tafra](https://tafra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) looks like a promising compromise. It uses numpy arrays under the hood but provides a pandas-like interface.